# How to modify the default text settings style in Rad Studio

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe

I'm developing and aplication with delphi XE7, and i need to modify all the components (labels, buttons, memos) text family font to a determined value and Bold. I know how to do it one per one, but i have too many components.

It's possible to modify the default Rad Studio text setting once, and applied to all the project?

Comment: I do this by deriving all forms from a common base. And then applying application wide policy there. Which is inherited by all forms. You really don't want to rely on applying a uniform look through dfm files.

Comment: Doing it at runtime is the right way. I just add, that e.g. CnPack has at least two ways for batch modification of certain component properties. Either you can run so called *Property Corrector* which is a set of rules that you apply for the scope that you want ([`screenshot`](http://i.imgur.com/BGB3Bl8.png)), or you can e.g. use so called *Component Selector* by which you can select multiple components by some rules (but that you can use just for the opened form).